# Dot notation - property / method

Tags: objective-c

Sanity check. Given this:

```
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSDate *start;
```

Then aren't these 2 lines of code identical?

Version 1:

```
self.start.description
```

Version 2:

```
[self.start description]
```

i.e. start.description calls the `description` method on the `start` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The result will be identical in both cases; properties are (mostly) just sugar around accessor methods written in the conventional Cocoa style.

I say "mostly" because there are some minor internal differences. Properties are added as meta-data to the runtime description of the Objective C class. You can, via some reflection, find out a list of properties that have been declared as such. This list is different from a list of methods that are named in the style of getter/setters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they're identical, and so is `[[self start] description]`

Answer (score 2):

Basically yes.

Around the property there is a setter and getter autosynchoronizsed. In the event that you use an @syncronize statement then you have a chance to influence how the setter, getter and property are named. If you autosynchronize the property's name is _start. The getter name is start and the setter name is setStart.

So

```
something = self.start
```

actually calls the getter and

```
self.start = something
```

calls the setter. 
Equivalents are:

```
something = [self start];
[self setStart:something];
```

If you ever want to access the instance variable directly then do so by:

```
_start = something;
something = _start;
```

In the event that you just use `@synthesize start;` then the equivalent would be:

```
start = something;
something = start;
```

That may well be confusing but `start` actually addresses the instance variable while `self.start` uses the setter/getter. This difference comes to vast importance when you do not ARC. Depending on the property parameters (e.g. assign, copy, retain, ...) the automatically generated getter and setter does some memeory management for you while the memory management is left to you when you work directly with the instance variable.